# What does "orangutan language" means?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

*Hey, im new here.*

In forum, i saw a Non-English stranger commented a text which is in *stranger's native language (not English)* that someone doesn't know of it, someone informally commented "Sorry i don't speak orangutan language" after the Non-English stranger commented it.

Help me, what's the meaning of Orangutan language. Is it means "gibberish", or others?

Thanks if answered it.

Comment: I would interpret it as a derogatory comment.  "Orangutan" is sometimes used (by people with poor social skills and poorer tastes) to refer to people of African or Asian background.

Comment: @Hot Licks, Yes, and I think the adjective you're looking for there is "racist"

Answer (score 3):

A person referring to a foreign speaker's native language as "orangutan language" is a racist slur that is rooted in European [colonialist race "science"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_racism) that viewed non-European people as less highly evolved and closer to apes. It's a sign that the person who said it is both an egotistical bigot who thinks that everyone who doesn't speak their own language is subhuman, and also that the person is trying to deflect away from their own ignorance of foreign languages by devaluing or mocking them.

Comment: It should be said that someone ignorant of general racial stereotypes might somehow think the speech resembles that of, say, [Cheetah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheeta), Tarzan's sidekick, and erroneously refer to him as an orangutan.  Not likely, but possible.  (Ref: [Hanlon's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor))

Comment: In a world full of malice, Hanlon's Razor is a terrible philosophy to live by. Racism is very much about malice - hatred towards broad (imagined) categories of people, and is sadly still quite common.

Comment: And racism is largely developed out of ignorance.  Understanding this makes it possible to actually do something about the problem.

Comment: As I said elsewhere:  In many ways the big problem is with people who are afraid to change their opinions as new insight comes to them. The willingness to question your beliefs is an important aspect of being a good human being.